# C# BackgroundWorker not firing for other people

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, backgroundworker

Maybe the question doesn't make sense, but the problem is that my program runs just fine for me. However, when I sent it to my brothers PC (relatively new one) to test it out, the `BackgroundWorker` is not firing.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(fetchList);
if (!bw.IsBusy)
{
    // I have checked that this stage is reached, and it is.
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I also debugged the function that is being called and it certainly is not firing. I am using `.NET 2.0` so I don't assume this should be the issue?

If it matters, the function being called by the worker is using 2 packages; `HtmlAgilityPack` and `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that we don't have enough context to help you with this issue.

Comment: There is nothing more for me to provide, I was just hoping someone might know a reason for this behaviour. I am new to C# and there might be something simple I don't know about which is causing this. If you need any more details please tell me what.

Comment: Well, we don't know who calls the code that builds the `BackgroundWorker`. We also don't know what triggers it. Further, we don't know if you're by happenstance building more than one. And we also don't know much about the box you deployed it to.

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I recall that if there is an exception in the `BackgroundWorker` thread, the worker cancels, and the exception is wrapped in the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` that you get in your `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`. Could this method "fetchList" be silently breaking?

Comment: @WillFaithfull No, `fetchList` is not executed at all. I tested by showing a label at the start of it which will not be displayed. I put the text "not busy"  right above the `RunWorkerAsync` function call which was printed but the one inside of the `fetchList` one is not shown at all. Which took me to the conclusion it is not running at all.

Comment: @neoistheone It's being ran by a click event. There is no problem with the event itself (in the click function I will set a "loading image" visible, which does appear). It seems like its not working for anyone regardless of their computer specs, only for me on the computer I made the program. What do you mean by "bulding more than one" ?

Comment: @Colandus, per your comment to Will, you're saying the `Click` event isn't working then, not the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @neoistheone No, I said the text will be shown inside the click event and also inside the `if(!bw.IsBusy)` right before it is supposed to execute `fetchList` although in `fetchList` it did not show me any text, which means it wasn't ran. To debug I am using `this.Error_label.Text = "passed";`

Comment: Is the label being updated inside the `BackgroundWorker` done so using a binding? If you're debugging, use `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show` inside the BackgroundWorker (*shudder*, I know, but it's really useful and thread independent)

Comment: @WillFaithfull To debug inside `fetchList` I use `this.BeginInvoke(new UI2Delegate(showError), "i am ran");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can count on *that* code work just fine.  What you can't count on is your fetchList method working properly.  If it throws an exception for any reason then that will *not* stop your program to tell you about it.  The exception is captured and passed as the e.Error property to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  You need to check it and take appropriate corrective actions, at a minimum let the user know.

You don't have a RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  So of course you can't know why fetchList doesn't work.

Comment: Just for more clarity: `bw.RunWorkerCompleted += MyClass_RunWorkerCompleted` and then `void MyClass_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e) { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString()); }` or similar

Comment: Do I need to give the users the `HTMLAgilityPack` dll-file and how about the Json package? The reason I ask this is because as stated it works fine for me, but not for others. If the case is as you say, that `fetchList` is actually ran but terminated, it must be because it didn't find either `HTMLAgilityPack` or the Json one. The code to print error threw an exception though, so I couldn't see the stacktrace.

Comment: Fix your code first.  You'll figure out what to do about the *real* problem when you get a good diagnostic.